# the code works with let but not with const. if i use a const the code will not work at all but i use var or let then the code works

Tags: javascript, constants

the code works with let but not with const.  if I use a constant  the code will not work at all but I use variable or let then the code works.

```
let x, y, z;
   x = 10;
   y = 20;
   z = x + y;
   document.querySelector("#statement").innerHTML =
    "When you add the var x and y the value of z is " + z + ".";
```

Comment: Assuming that this is Javascript, write it like this: `const x = 10; const y = 20; const z = x + y;`  A `const` declaration requires an initializer.

Comment: Welcome to SO. If you have a language-specific question, you should add the language as a tag, as the question is only interesting and answerable for someone with knowledge about the language which the question is about.

Answer (score 1):

Consts need to be initialized, so `const x, y, z` won't work.

Answer (score 1):

The `const` variables need to be initialized. So, your code would be:

```
const x = 10;
const y = 20
const z = x + y; // or just seriously assign 30 to it

document.querySelector("#statement").innerHTML =
    "When you add the var x and y the value of z is " + z + ".";
```

Also keep in mind that `const` variables cannot be reassigned.

If you want the variables' values to change, use `var` or `let` :

```
var x, y, z;

x = 10;
y = 20;
z = x + y;

document.querySelector("#statement").innerHTML =
    "When you add the var x and y the value of z is " + z + ".";
```

Answer (score 1):

Consts need to be initialized

```
const x = 10 //work

const y //error
y = 20
```

and const is immutable

```
const x = 10
x = 10 // error
```